# Sort numpy matrix along axis but keep values together

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix where the 2nd axis (z/depth) is info that goes together; think image where the three values for each pixel go together.  Mine is [y, x, classifier] instead of [R,G,B].

```
a = np.array([[[10,15,1], [5,10,3], [10,5,3]],
               [[5,25,2], [20,20,3], [5,15,1]]]
```

I would like to sort them by 1st and 2nd axis so that smallest axis 1+2 value is top left and largest is bottom right.  However when i do `np.sort(a, axis = 0, kind='stable')` it only moves the first item and doesnt keep them as a set.  I also tried:

```
idx = np.argsort(a, axis=0)
sorted_a = a[idx]
```

But that got super wacky and seemed to repeat the entire matrix multiple times with different ordering.

End result should be:

```
[[[5,10,3], [5,15,1], [5,25,2]],
[[10,5,3], [10,15,1],[20,20,3]]]
```

I would prefer a method that uses the built-in NumPy methods so I can replace my current simple sorting loops that ended up getting quite cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a vectorized way -

```
In [211]: a2D = a.reshape(-1,a.shape[-1])

In [212]: (a2D[np.lexsort(a2D.T[::-1])]).reshape(a.shape)
Out[212]: 
array([[[ 5, 10,  3],
        [ 5, 15,  1],
        [ 5, 25,  2]],

       [[10,  5,  3],
        [10, 15,  1],
        [20, 20,  3]]])
```

Explanation : Crux of the solution would be with [`lexsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) which as the docs state, sorts grouped items keeping certain priority order. In our case, the order being the left-most element being most important and so on until end of each row. Based on the grouping, we sort and hence get the new row order. We use it on a 2D reshaped array. So, we reshape before and after lex-sorting.

Comment: Can you break that down a bit for me?  Reshaping it as a 2d array seems like a great idea.  How is lexsort getting it into order and why is it nessecary to work on the Transpose of the 2d?

Comment: @DChaps Added into post.

Comment: Thanks.  For the reshape(-1,...   the docs term -1 as an 'unknown dimension'.  In that line are we saying "I know the dimension of the second axis (a.shape[-1]) but I dont know/care about the first axis so you figure it out numpy"?  My guess is that's a more reliable way instead of specifying both axis sizes in case the data has an extra row/column than usual.

Comment: @DChaps Yeah, you got it there.

Comment: This worked great.  Because my data isn't as simple as my example (when is it ever) I added a simple row sort afterward and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `sorted` and define sort key using `operator.itemgetter`:

```
import operator

a = np.array([[[10,15,1], [5,10,3], [10,5,3]],
               [[5,25,2], [20,20,3], [5,15,1]]])
shp = a.shape
np.array(sorted(a.reshape(-1, 3), key=operator.itemgetter(0, 1))).reshape(shp)
```

Output:

```
array([[[ 5, 10,  3],
        [ 5, 15,  1],
        [ 5, 25,  2]],

       [[10,  5,  3],
        [10, 15,  1],
        [20, 20,  3]]])
```

Comment: Or instead of `operator.itemgetter` you can use a `lambda` function like this: `np.array(sorted(a.reshape(-1, 3), key = lambda v: [v[0], v[1]])).reshape(a.shape)`

Comment: I modified it for my 2d array of length xx ie [xx,2] - tmp=np.array(sorted(xy_lower_tmp.reshape(-1, 2), key=operator.itemgetter(0, 1))).reshape(shp) and it worked.